# Matlab legend for plotting in loop with different colors

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, colors, legend

I have a code in matlab in which i'm plotting several 2d points, which belong in 16 classes, so i use 16 different colors. Is there any easy way to have a legend that denote the class name for each color?

Code looks something like this:

```
for i=1:length(data) 
    color = class_color(i);
    plot(data(i,1),data(i,2),'*','Color',color);
    hold on;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could plot all the data points for a single class together with logical indexing.

Assuming you have the classes defined somewhere, say in `class_number` which is the same  length as `data`, with entries ranging from `1` to `16`, and `c_colors`, a cell array of length 16 with the colors corresponding to each class: then

```
for jj = 1:16
  mask = (class_number==jj);
  plot(data(mask,1),data(mask,2),'*','Color',c_colors{jj});
  hold on
end
hold off
```

(Not tested).

Then you can store the names of the classes in a cell array and call `legend` on that.

```
class_name{1} = 'Type a';
class_name{2} = 'Type b';
% etc, up to
class_name{15} = 'Type o';
class_name{16} = 'Type p';
legend(class_name);
```

Comment: My problem is not how to call the legend with multiple values, rather than correlating the colors of the dots to a specific value of the legend

Comment: @ConstantinePat. Okay, not sure how to add it to your original version of the plot, but have suggested another way of plotting which should work with it.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bad idea to use 16 colors to differentiate data points. Like colors will blend together. I suggest using different markers+colors. Four markers like `'*'` , `'x'`, `'+'`, `'.'`, etc. and four colors for each marker. Then you can use `legend('Class 1','Class 2', Class n')`. It should show each marker of the specific color. This will probably be the case when it is best to write out each line without loop and add %comments after each marker/color/class describing what it is, in case you have to come back to this code later. It is not really a solution you are asking for, but this is how I would do it.

Comment: The marker-color idea is a good one, since i could differentiate between subclasses, although the "legend('class1',...etc) part doesn't work, since the legend doesn't know the corresponding classes. It just refers to the first 16 samples, which happen to be of ay class.